# How to capitalize the TextField value first letter of the first word for each sentence?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, textfield

Is such a thing possible? And is it possible to follow [these rules](https://www.esolcourses.com/uk-english/beginners-grammar/capital-letters/lesson-7/grammar.html)?

[similar questions](https://www.esolcourses.com/uk-english/beginners-grammar/capital-letters/lesson-7/grammar.html) have been asked before but they are forsimple capital the first letter of first word and not more

Comment: Where are you testing it? Web or android..?

Comment: android @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: You can use `textCapitalization` property of a TextField widget. Also do take a reference for detailed API info here Text Capitalization Official API - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextCapitalization-class.html

```
TextField(
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
    )
```

here you can use couple of options: TextCapitalization.words, TextCapitalization.sentences

**Option 2**: Using `.toUpperCase() method`
After String put .toUpperCase()

```
var string = "text".toUpperCase()
```

Comment: ur solution is correct, but I need to automatically generate texts like "My favorite film is The Matrix. And I think.....".

Comment: what do you mean by automatically generate text?